# Service Broker issue with multiple queues

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am not that much familiar with service broker functionality in SQL Server, would appropriate any of your help for below problem

I have created 2 services **Initiator and Target services**, 2 queues **SourceQ and DestinationQ**, 2 Message type **requestMessage and responseMessage** and a contract **ContractMessage**. On one of the table I have created a trigger which will call initiator service as below

```
BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle              
        FROM SERVICE [InitiatorService]           
        TO SERVICE N'TargetService'           
        ON CONTRACT [ContractMessage]          
        WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
```

IntitatorService is on SourceQ and TargetService is on DestinationQ.

The problem is I am getting data to SourceQ but not DestinationQ.Checked all permission everything looks fine.

Can anyone help me to understand why data is not moving from SourceQ to destinationQ?

```
select * from [dbo].[SourceQ] --getting data
select * from [dbo].[DestinationQ] --not getting data
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the `CREATE SERVICE` DDL to your question and the `RECEIVE` code.

Comment: Is there anything in the sys.transmission_queue?

Comment: Can you show the code that handles the dialog's messages on the destination side and sends the response back to the initiator? Do you have an activation procedure there?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is putting data into SourceQ? From your description, I'm not seeing that.

Comment: Hi Dan, we is the code used to create service                                                   CREATE SERVICE [InitiatorService]  AUTHORIZATION [dbo]  ON QUEUE  dbo.SourceQ
GO 
CREATE SERVICE [TargetService]  AUTHORIZATION [dbo]  ON QUEUE  dbo. DestinationQ ([ContractMessage])
GO

Comment: Note this functionality was perfectly working fine when it was running in SQL server 2012. When migrated to SQL 2019 (using .bak) it is not working. After migration when noticed that service broker was not enabled after enabling it we see data is not moving to destination queue

Comment: HI David, there is no rows in sys.transmission_queue